# Revert ElasticSearch field type without data losing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a Kibana not owned by me.
As of now it contains 1000+ fields (generated from JSON inputs).
There are few fields which were (maybe manually configured as String), and few visualizations which used these fields.
At some moment the index fields list was refreshed, and these fields became Number. And for some time were indexed as numbers.
Now we have conflicts "The type of this field changes across indices. It is unavailable for many analysis functions."

Is there any chance to convert it to String without losing the data?

Answer (score 0):

In general this will require the following procedure
backup the offending indices using some tool
Delete the indices
and restore the indices from the backup but make sure to change the mapping of that type.
I would recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump for this purpose.